# xargs -P messes stdout

Tags: shell, find, stdout, xargs

I trying to achieve parallel find to reduce big FS traversing time:

```
find $1 -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d | xargs -P5 -n1 find
```

works good but five (-P5) "find" processes run in parallel mess their output so strings break apart sometimes. How to rid off this behavior? 
Should be а usual problem with xargs but seems nobody uses its parallel feature.

Comment: Trying using: find $1 -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -P5 -n1 find

Comment: good point, but how to force all processes to write to separate files?

Comment: Cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44569541/xargs-output-buffering-p-parallel

Answer (score 2):

You can write to separate files using

```
find $1 -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -P5 -n1 -I{} sh -c 'find "{}" > "/tmp/{}.dirlist.txt"'
```

And then `cat`ing them together at the end.