# xargs output buffering -P parallel

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a bash function that i call in parallel using xargs -P like so

```
 echo ${list} | xargs -n 1 -P 24 -I@ bash -l -c 'myAwesomeShellFunction @'
```

Everything works fine but output is messed up for obvious reasons (no buffering)

Trying to figure out a way to buffer output effectively. I was thinking I could use awk, but I'm not good enough to write such a script and I can't find anything worthwhile on google? Can someone help me write this "output buffer" in sed or awk? Nothing fancy, just accumulate output and spit it out after process terminates. I don't care the order that shell functions execute, just need their output buffered... Something like:

```
 echo ${list} | xargs -n 1 -P 24 -I@ bash -l -c 'myAwesomeShellFunction @ | sed -u ""'
```

P.s. I tried to use stdbuf as per
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe but did not work, i specified buffering on o and e but output still unbuffered:

```
 echo ${list} | xargs -n 1 -P 24 -I@ stdbuf -i0 -oL -eL bash -l -c 'myAwesomeShellFunction @'
```

Here's my first attempt, this only captures first line of output:

```
 $ bash -c "echo stuff;sleep 3; echo more stuff" | awk '{while (( getline line) > 0 )print "got ",$line;}'
 $ got  stuff
```

Comment: Don't tell me to use GNU parallel, I don't have it installed and getting it installed is questionable as I'm running on RHEL6

Comment: Why not redirect outputs to a file, using the `-I@` to generate a unique filename for each task? You can then `cat` all the files. You can even use `mktemp`

Comment: Don't wanna mess around with files

Comment: BTW, `-I@` is problematic being substituted into `bash -c` if you don't trust your data. If one of your list entries contains `$(/tmp/evil-prog)`, then you just had code injected. Much *much* safer to pass data out-of-band from code.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Can you comment on why `stdbuf` doesn't work?

Comment: @BenjaminW., turning on line buffering tells an individual instance not to try to perform writes shorter than a single line (assuming you don't have a single line that goes over your buffer size), but it doesn't stop your lines from being interleaved across multiple instances. Even larger-than-line buffers don't prevent the boundaries of the buffer (and thus the boundaries of a write) from being at an undesirable cutoff point.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Got it! Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This isn't *quite* atomic if your output is longer than a page (4kb typically), but for most cases it'll do:

```
xargs -P 24 bash -c 'for arg; do printf "%s\n" "$(myAwesomeShellFunction "$arg")"; done' _
```

The magic here is the command substitution: `$(...)` creates a subshell (a `fork()`ed-off copy of your shell), runs the code `...` in it, and then reads that in to be substituted into the relevant position in the outer script.

Note that we don't need `-n 1` (if you're dealing with a large number of arguments -- for a small number it may improve parallelization), since we're iterating over as many arguments as each of your 24 parallel `bash` instances is passed.

---

If you want to make it truly atomic, you can do that with a lockfile:

```
# generate a lockfile, arrange for it to be deleted when this shell exits
lockfile=$(mktemp -t lock.XXXXXX); export lockfile
trap 'rm -f "$lockfile"' 0

xargs -P 24 bash -c '
  for arg; do
    {
      output=$(myAwesomeShellFunction "$arg")
      flock -x 99
      printf "%s\n" "$output"
    } 99>"$lockfile"
  done
' _
```

Comment: That's really clever, didn't realize command substitution did that. Output can only occupy 1 page? Mine is pretty much guaranteed to be less than 4kb, unless something really unusual happens. Number of arguments is typically <24, this is upper limit, n1 was there just for safety really... This worked, so awesome!!!

Comment: It *can* occupy multiple pages, but has more of a chance of being split into multiple writes in that case, so if you had multiple processes finishing at the same time (within a few milliseconds of each other?) combined with multi-page output, then you might lose the atomicity.