# How can I make 'xargs' execute for all files found by 'find' command in bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, git

I have `*.test.*` files inside my `src` folder and I wanna find authors who contributed the most. I came up with command below

```bash
find ./src/ -name "*.test.*" -print0 | xargs git --no-pager blame -0 -p | grep "^author " | uniq -c
```

but unfortunately, for some reason it works only for the first file. How can I run that command for all files found by `find`? Or do I have to somehow "collect" results of `git` command execution

I've googled that `xargs` has `-L` argument, but it didn't help. What am I doing wrong?

Expected result should be like output below

```
2 author Cat Tom
1 author Mouse Jerry
1 author Sponge Bob
```

Comment: Have a look at `git blame -h`: The help tells you that _blame_ accepts only one filename.

Comment: you got your contribution calculation wrong. see UPDATE section in my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
find ./src/ -name "*.test.*" -print0 |
    xargs -0 -n1 git --no-pager blame -p |
    grep "^author " | uniq -c
```

`-0` is an argument for `xargs` so it must be passed to `xargs` not to `git blame`.

`git blame` works one file at a time so make `xargs` to pass one file using `-n1`.

Answer (score 3):

Did some modifications:

- `xargs -n1` to execute line-by-line
- we don't need `--no-pager` since git knows that it's piped
- deleted `author` with `grep -Po "(?<=^author ).*"`
- add `sort` before `uniq` because `uniq` counts only consecutive lines.
- add `sort -nr` after `uniq` to sort contributors in reversed order.
- add line numbers to see an author's rank with `nl`.
- and finally with 400 files it takes 8 seconds. so added `xargs -P0` to run git for each file in parallel and it took 1 second.

```
$ time find ./src/ -name "*.twig" -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 -P0 git blame -p | grep -Po "(?<=^author ).*" | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | nl -s': '
     1:     543 Twist
     2:     273 chuzhaikinadv
     3:     239 Anton
     4:     225 zayceva
     5:     204 Natalia Baganova
     6:     113 Nastie Deminka
     7:     103 Lakhaev Andrey
     8:      79 sergey.ivanov
     9:      72 alnidok
    10:      70 Kalchenko Ilia
    11:      41 Andrey Klimenko
    12:      38 a.dadaev
    13:      30 dilya
    14:      20 a.kaledin
    15:      17 George
    16:      16 Svetoslav Onosov
    17:      14 Andrey Smirnov
    18:      13 Mustafaeva Dilya
    19:      13 George Barlukov
    20:      10 andrewsmirnov
    21:       7 silentmantra
    22:       6 Sergey
    23:       6 Alexander Nenashev
    24:       5 Задорожний Александр
    25:       5 Dilya
    26:       4 over_ilaj
    27:       4 egoprimary
    28:       4 Dilya Mustafaeva
    29:       3 Zharova Yaroslava
    30:       3 Nastie
    31:       3 Irina Demchenko
    32:       2 Александра Храпкова
    33:       2 Vadim
    34:       2 Sharipova
    35:       2 LaFut
    36:       2 Kozyreva
    37:       2 Andrey Lakhaev
    38:       1 e757c3db6bfaf171b1c6aa51b3d9798c605a51a8 1 1 1
    39:       1 DESKTOP-0N4O88L\dev
    40:       1 Andrey Kuznetsov
    41:       1 Alexander Zadoroznyi

real    0m0.917s
user    0m10.946s
sys     0m3.047s
```

**UPDATE**
`git blame -p` counts only commits by an author. Imho it's not a real contribution. Since we are using `git blame` I suppose we are interested in *LINE CHANGES*. Luckily `git blame` has `--line-porcelain` what exactly we need to count line changes by an author.
Ok, but in my case `xargs` failed to deliver such big data in consistent manner and every execution the result was different. Oops, we have problem even with counting commits! I believe this line from the first example with `xargs` is wrong!

```
38:       1 e757c3db6bfaf171b1c6aa51b3d9798c605a51a8 1 1 1
```

I guess the problem is `xargs`' buffering thus providing `grep` with broken lines. The problem is described here and the solution at first glance doesnt seem elegant: [xargs output buffering -P parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44569541/xargs-output-buffering-p-parallel)

Installed `GNU Parallel` and launched the command, it's consistent and fast enough!
So first:

```
Here goes a vote against xargs in favor of gnu parallel...
```

And the results. As you can see `Natalia Baganova` takes the 2nd place though counting commits only gives here only the 5th. So that's real contribution opposed to just counting commits:

```
$ $ time find ./src/ -name "*.twig" -print0 | parallel -0 git blame --line-porcelain | grep -Po "(?<=^author ).*" | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | nl -s': '
     1:    4996 Twist
     2:    4121 Natalia Baganova
     3:    2771 zayceva
     4:    2405 Anton
     5:    2361 chuzhaikinadv
     6:    1113 George
     7:    1081 Nastie Deminka
     8:     750 Kalchenko Ilia
     9:     712 alnidok
    10:     516 Lakhaev Andrey
    11:     383 Andrey Smirnov
    12:     365 dilya
    13:     325 a.dadaev
    14:     301 Andrey Klimenko
    15:     291 sergey.ivanov
    16:     134 Задорожний Александр
    17:     124 George Barlukov
    18:     116 Sergey
    19:      59 egoprimary
    20:      43 a.kaledin
    21:      42 Mustafaeva Dilya
    22:      41 Svetoslav Onosov
    23:      38 Alexander Nenashev
    24:      26 andrewsmirnov
    25:      25 Nastie
    26:      20 silentmantra
    27:      18 Zharova Yaroslava
    28:      16 Dilya Mustafaeva
    29:      15 Andrey Kuznetsov
    30:       9 over_ilaj
    31:       9 Dilya
    32:       6 Sharipova
    33:       6 LaFut
    34:       3 Александра Храпкова
    35:       3 Irina Demchenko
    36:       3 Andrey Lakhaev
    37:       2 Vadim
    38:       2 Kozyreva
    39:       2 DESKTOP-0N4O88L\dev
    40:       2 Alexander Zadoroznyi

real    0m1.334s
user    0m10.418s
sys     0m4.043s
```